# conversion using parse vs convert what is the difference between them

Tags: c#

Why do I have to use `.ToString()` for this code to work:

```
confirmedAcceptance = int.Parse(dr["confirmedAcceptance"].ToString());
```

This creates error:

```
confirmedAcceptance = int.Parse(dr["confirmedAcceptance"]);
```

Comment: Looks like XY problem. What type `dr` is? What is the return type of `dr`'s indexer? If `dr` stands for `DataRow`, that you don't need neither `Parse`, nor `Convert`. Just cast value to appropriate type, like this, if that field is really `int` one: `confirmedAcceptance = (int)dr["confirmedAcceptance"];`

Comment: Full explanation: [Uses Of Int.Parse, Convert.ToInt32, And int.TryParse (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uses-of-int-parse-convert-toint-and-int-tryparse/)

Answer (score 0):

int.Parse tries to parse the certain Object into an INT. This can go as far as converting a string to INT (in which he calculates it) there is no certain way we know if it actually will work. Thats why we have TryParse which instantly catches the Programm if it actually not works

Convert uses a manually programmed Conversion. like Convert.ToInt() it has implicit Conversions for Double/Etc.

So if u know that it is supported, always use Convert, if u maybe dont know whats coming in and have to poker a bit. Use Parse and if best TryParse..

Comment: "always use Convert" sounds very, very out-and-out. I'd say "do not use `Convert` class unless you really need it"

Answer (score 0):

The ‘Parse’ method accepts a string as a parameter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0
The ‘Convert’ method also accepts a string as a parameter.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0

When you pass an integer to Int.Parse() or Convert.ToInt32()  methods you are not passing the correct data type to the method.

Comment: What exactly does this help with.

Comment: He asked why he had to convert to a string in order for his code to work the reason being the method accepts an argument that has a data type of string.